# Creating multiple divs (or table) on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a rather basic calendar.  Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="calendar">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-1-4" id="month-1"><h3>January</h3></div>
            <div class="col-1-4" id="month-2"><h3>February</h3></div>
            <div class="col-1-4" id="month-3"><h3>March</h3></div>
            <div class="col-1-4" id="month-4"><h3>April</h3></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-1-4" id="month-5"><h3>May</h3></div>
            <div class="col-1-4" id="month-6"><h3>June</h3></div>
            <div class="col-1-4" id="month-7"><h3>July</h3></div>
            <div class="col-1-4" id="month-8"><h3>August</h3></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-1-4" id="month-9"><h3>September</h3></div>
            <div class="col-1-4" id="month-10"><h3>October</h3></div>
            <div class="col-1-4" id="month-11"><h3>November</h3></div>
            <div class="col-1-4" id="month-12"><h3>December</h3></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

On a hover, I would like for the days of that particular month to be displayed.  Instead of creating a table for each month like so:

```
<table class="days">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                ....
                <tr>
                    <td>26</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>28</td>
                    <td>29</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                    <td>31</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
</table>
```

or creating 35 divs for each month, is there a way to create one table or one set of divs that can be used for each month?

Obviously, the problem is that the arrangement and number of days between months differs.  Is there a script that can be written to accommodate this?  This way seems like it would be a lot cleaner and efficient.

Or would it be simpler to just handle each month individually?

Thank you.

Comment: I had done same thing using Datejs. if you want i can give that.

Comment: If you don't mind, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is javascript code that generate table as per your requirement.

```
var _Days = new Array("sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thr", "fri", "sat"); //declare 7 days 

function getCalendar(){
var tempDate = new Date("2014/09/01"); //create date object of month and year you want create calendar here. 
var firstDayOfMonth = tempDate.moveToFirstDayOfMonth().getDayName();
var daysInMonth = tempDate.moveToLastDayOfMonth().getDate();
var i = 1, j = 1, html = '<table>';
//create header 
html += '<tr><th scope="col">sun</th><th scope="col">sun</th>' +
                                 '<th scope="col">tue</th><th scope="col">wed</th> ' +
                                 '<th scope="col">thr</th><th scope="col">fri</th> ' +
                                 '<th scope="col">sat</th></tr>'
while (j <= daysInMonth) {
                html += '<tr>';
                $(_Days).each(function (index) {
                    if ((this == firstDayOfMonth || j > 1) && (j <= daysInMonth)) {                 
                            html += '<td>' + j + '</td>'
                        j++;
                    } else {
                        html += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
                    }
                });
                html += '</tr>'
            }
}
html+='</table>';
```

Table html is ready now you can use it as per your requiement.
Do not forgot to add reference of Datejs.

Answer (score 1):

Creating an HTML calendar can be overwhelming, for the reasons you provided.

However, it can be done with a little HTML, CSS, and a few lines of jQuery.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="Days">
  <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div>
  <div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div><div>9</div><div>10</div>
  <div>11</div><div>12</div><div>13</div><div>14</div><div>15</div>
  <div>16</div><div>17</div><div>18</div><div>19</div><div>20</div>
  <div>21</div><div>22</div><div>23</div><div>24</div><div>25</div>
  <div>26</div><div>27</div><div>28</div><div>29</div><div>30</div>
  <div>31</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#Days {
  background:#ccc;
  height:300px;
  width:400px;
}

#Days div {
  float:left;
  width: 13.78571%;
  height:16.1667%;
  margin-right:0.5%;
  margin-bottom:0.5%;
  text-align:right;
  background:white;
}
```

The `margin` styles create the borders with little work by the browser.  (A jsPerf may be useful to prove this.)

Note that `#Days div` `width` and `height` are percentages.  Including margins, they are equal to 100/7 (7 days in a week) and 100/6 (a calendar may have up to 6 rows).

**jQuery**:

```
function showMonth(month,year) {
  var dayStart = new Date(year, month-1, 1).getDay();
  var daysInMonth = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();

  $('#Days div').first().css('margin-left',14.287571*dayStart+'%');
  $('#Days div').show();
  $('#Days div').eq(daysInMonth-1).nextAll().hide();
} //showMonth
```

`dayStart` holds the first day of the month (0=Sun, 1=Mon, etc.)  The first `#Days div` is simply styled so that its left margin pushes day 1 into the correct position.

`daysInMonth` is what it says.  We simply hide every day past the last day.  Before doing so, we show all the days, in case we're changing from month to month.

**[This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ygrf734o/15/)** includes your requirement to change month on `hover`.

Comment: Actually, I have a follow-up.  If I had the HTML of my original post, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/n415kh68/ would this still be possible?  From your example it looks like I'd have to have "Days divs" for each month, which is what I was trying to avoid.  Is it possible to move all of those "Days divs" to a different month?

Comment: Sure.  jQuery's append function can move an element from one parent to another:  http://api.jquery.com/append/.